# How to setup repository decorators in katharsis

Tags: java, rest, katharsis

I'm trying to use repository decorators in katharsis (version 2.8.2) but the thing isn't working so far. I've extended `ResourceRepositoryDecoratorBase`, implemented `RepositoryDecoratorFactory` and provided them thru a `SimpleModule` to `KatharsisInvokerBuilder` instance.

The module and all its stuff it's being picked by katharisis, but when I do an HTTP request the decorators seem absent (no log traces) and the underlying repository receives the request, doing its work properly.

In a debugging session I've found that the list of repositories in method `ModuleRegistry.applyRepositoryRegistration()` is empty, so obviously at that point there is nothing to decorate (but it's quite strange, because regular repositories are working).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

You could try [posting the issue](https://github.com/katharsis-project/katharsis-framework/issues) on the katharsis github